# Sonarqube: "Invoke method(s) only conditionally" cannot figure out the reason

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am getting a

> Invoke method(s) only conditionally

warning from SonarQube for the following code.

```
  void deleteMyTableRow(Integer id) {
    if (myTable.deleteById(id) != 1) {
      log.error(LogMessageBuilder
          .message(
              "There was an error deleting id: {0}",
              String.valueOf(accountId))
          .cause("Some cause.")
          .effect("Some effect.")
          .solution("Some solution.")
          .build());
      throw new UpdateFailureException("my_table");
    }
  }
```

I thought the issue is with how I was concatenating this initially. Initially it was `"There was an error deleting id: "+id`, but changing it to string format (as given in sonarqube docs for this warning) didnt help. Could someone point out what is wrong with this?

The full message that SonarQube is showing me is here:

https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2629

Comment: Is it saying that the entire `LogMessageBuilder` chain shouldn't be evaluated unless necessary?

Comment: @AndyTurner i am not sure, maybe not. I use `LogMessageBuilder` not only here, and the other logs that look exactly like this , they dont have this sonarqube warning. The only difference is that this `log` is in an `if` condition, whereas other logs are in the `catch` block

Comment: @AndyTurner i tried removing the `id` from the logger, and i still have the error. I think the problem is with the `LogMessageBuilder` class, it uses `MessageFormat.format(pattern, arguments)` , it s written by someone else, I guess i will leave this warning for now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove the zero:

```
"There was an error deleting id: {}"
```